# Non-virtual methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, virtual-functions

I need to call from the category a concrete implementation of the method (even if it's overridden). Is it possible? (Just in case: **I know, all methods in Objective-C are virtual.**)

```
// class A
@interface A

- (void)foo;

@end

@implementation A

- (void)foo
{
    NSLog(@"initial foo");
}

@end

// subclass of A
@interface A1: A

@end

@implementation A1

- (void)foo
{
    NSLog(@"overridden foo");
}

@end

// category to A
@interface A (Category)

- (void)bar;

@end

@impletemtation A (Category)

- (void)bar
{
    [self foo];    // probably, I should specify here what exactly must be self
                   // but I don't know how
}

@end

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
A1 *a = [[A1 alloc] init];

[a bar];    // now the "overridden foo" string will be printed
            //  my goal is to print "initial foo" !!!
```

Comment: Do you really want to break encapsulation like that?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. Nevertheless, I'm curious to know if it's possible in theory.

Comment: This would be a giant code smell, but did you try `[super foo];`?

Comment: C'mon guys, yes, it's bad! But it's interesting :) If I call super in a category it refers to the superclass of A (not to A itself).

Comment: who downvoted? it is a great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you do not have to change anything.

You can get a function pointer to the implementation of every method on a specific class:

```
A* receiver = …
IMP impOnA = class_getMethodImplementation( [A class], @selector( foo ));
((void (*)(id, SEL))impOnA)( receiver, @selector( foo ) ); // or whatever signature
```

Comment: Would be nice if you slightly update the answer. The compiler doesn't let you to use impOnA as a function name with multiple params, you have to convert it to the **void (* imp)(id, SEL)**. Thanks a lot, it's an elegant solution.

Comment: Of course, you are correct. One has to cast the function pointer. (Sorry, typed in Safari.) I added it.

Comment: Oh, I you're from the Ukraine. Let's have a good match tonight – and a german victory. ;-)

Comment: Congratulations! Germans were better this time. But I should say our team has become much better since last time I watched their game.

Comment: C u at the final. ;-)

Comment: We'll be there B-)

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt [Matt Gallagher's supersequent implementation approach](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html) to find the specific method you want to invoke.

Alternatively, you could just set the class temporarily:

```
Class realClass = object_getClass(self);
Class fakeClass = [A class];

object_setClass(self, fakeClass);
[self foo];
object_setClass(self, realClass);
```

(I'm on my phone, so not 100% sure about the syntax, but the idea should work.)

Comment: He wants to select a specific implementation, not change the class of an object. This may cause harm to the implementation of `-foo`.

Comment: What kind of harm do you specifically mean?

Answer (score 0):

Finally. indeed method swizzing works

```
@implementation A (Category)  

- (void)quux
{
  NSLog(@"quux");
}

- (void)bar
{
  Class class = [A class];

  SEL originalSelector = @selector(foo);
  SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(quux);

  Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
  Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

  method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
  [self quux];
  method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the intention, but it doesn't solve the problem. Here you temporarily replace implementation, but I don't need it. All I need is the method foo from the class A to be called.

Answer (score -1):

This may solve your problem:

```
// class A
@interface A

- (void)foo;

@end

@implementation A

- (void)foo
{
    [self fooImpl];
}

- (void)fooImpl
{
    NSLog(@"initial foo");
}

@end

// subclass of A
@interface A1: A

@end

@implementation A1

- (void)foo
{
    NSLog(@"overridden foo");
}

@end

// category to A
@interface A (Category)

- (void)bar;

@end

@impletemtation A (Category)

- (void)bar
{
    [self fooImpl];    // probably, I should specify here what exactly must be self
                   // but I don't know how
}

@end

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
A1 *a = [[A1 alloc] init];

[a bar];    // now the "overridden foo" string will be printed
            //  my goal is to print "initial foo" !!!
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that. In my case A is UIViewController and I can't rewrite it's implementation.